# openIMAJ face detection - uncaught IOException

Tags: java, exception, face-detection, openimaj

I have this method(simplified) for detecting faces(count) on images(URLs):

```
private int processImage(String urlString) {
    InputStream is = null;
    URLConnection resource;
    int facesCount = 0;
    try {
        resource = new URL(urlString).openConnection();
        resource.setConnectTimeout(200);
        resource.setReadTimeout(1000);
        resource.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

        String type = resource.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
        if (!type.startsWith("image/")) {
            throw new IOException("Not an image (Content-Type:" + type + ")");
        }
        is = resource.getInputStream();
        MBFImage mbfimage = ImageUtilities.readMBF(is);
        facesCount = faceDetector.detectFaces(Transforms.calculateIntensity(mbfimage)).size();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("oops");
    }
    return facesCount;
}
```

It works well, but if the image is somewhat corrupted (for example [this test image](https://www.kosna.cz/test.jpg)), i get this error:

> Error: Cannot decode the image for the type : Occurs in:
>   com.sun.media.jai.opimage.CodecRIFUtil java.io.IOException: Source
>   stream does not support seeking backwards.    at
>   com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.CodecUtils.toIOException(CodecUtils.java:76)
>     at
>   com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.FPXImageDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(FPXImageDecoder.java:40)
>     at
>   com.sun.media.jai.opimage.CodecRIFUtil.create(CodecRIFUtil.java:88)
>     at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.FPXRIF.create(FPXRIF.java:46)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)    at
>   javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
>     at
>   javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
>     at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
>     at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.StreamRIF.create(StreamRIF.java:102)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)    at
>   javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
>     at
>   javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
>     at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
>     at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:819)   at
>   javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)   at
>   javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getColorModel(RenderedOp.java:2242)    at
>   javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getAsBufferedImage(PlanarImage.java:2498)
>     at
>   javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getAsBufferedImage(PlanarImage.java:2546)
>     at org.openimaj.image.ExtendedImageIO.read(ExtendedImageIO.java:162)
>     at org.openimaj.image.ImageUtilities.readMBF(ImageUtilities.java:273)
>     at image.ImageThread.processImage(ImageThread.java:233)     at
>   image.ImageThread.main(ImageThread.java:255) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source stream does not support
>   seeking backwards.    at
>   com.sun.media.jai.codec.SegmentedSeekableStream.(SegmentedSeekableStream.java:200)
>     at
>   com.sun.media.jai.codec.SegmentedSeekableStream.(SegmentedSeekableStream.java:262)
>     at
>   com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.fpx.StructuredStorage.getFat(StructuredStorage.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.fpx.StructuredStorage.(StructuredStorage.java:131)
>     at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.fpx.FPXImage.(FPXImage.java:110)
>     at
>   com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.FPXImageDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(FPXImageDecoder.java:38)
>     ... 28 more

and the program hangs. I want to catch that exception, log it and go on.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Does it print "oops"?

Comment: @immibis no, it doesnt...

Comment: Then you may have found a bug in OpenIMAJ.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. I was using old version of openIMAJ (1.1.3). The latest version is 1.3.1 which works well. I didn't notice, because I overlooked the version numbers.